# Проблема с циклом (for)

Tags: java, android, for

Мой цикл не работает.
У меня функция проверяет файлы игры. Если хоть одна контрольная сумма не совпадает, должно возвращать false.
Если все файлы верны, true.
Что я сделал не так?

```
public boolean isGameFilesValid(Context context, int gameID) {
    loadGameFilesList(context, gameID);
    for(int i = 0; i < gamesFiles.size(); i++) {
        File file = new File(Config.getGamePath(gameID)+gamesFiles.get(i).path);
        if(!file.exists() || !Utils.checkMD5(context, gamesFiles.get(i).size, file)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Функция в цикл заходит, файлы находит?
После создания объекта file добавьте System.out.println(file.getName()) и убедитесь что файл получен

Comment: все находит, результаты проверки мне пишутся в лог. просто возвращается false почему-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас лишний `return`. Получается что всегда в конце первой итерации цикла срабатывает `return true;`

```java
public boolean isGameFilesValid() {
    for() {
        if(!file.exists() || !Utils.checkMD5(....)) { 
            return false;
        }
        return true; // здесь не должно быть
    }
    return false; // а здесь должен быть return true;
}
```